Error 404 when accessing API via Nginx and Express
I have set up a server with Nginx to serve a React application and proxy_pass requests to an Express API. The Nginx configuration includes a location block to proxy requests prefixed with /api/ to my Express server running on port 3001. Here's a snippet of my Nginx configuration:
server {
    server_name example.com;

    root /var/www/example.com/html;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}


When I attempt to access the API endpoint https://example.com/api/posts, I receive a 404 Not Found error. However, accessing http://localhost:3001/api/posts directly on the server returns the expected data.
Here is an excerpt from the Nginx access log showing the 404 error:
192.168.1.1 - - [27/Jun/2024:12:34:56 +0000] "GET /api/posts HTTP/1.1" 404 144 "https://example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

I have verified that:
My Express server is running and listening on port 3001.
The /api/posts route is correctly defined in my Express application.
I have restarted Nginx after making configuration changes.
There are no apparent firewall issues blocking the connection.
Despite these checks, Nginx continues to return a 404 error when attempting to proxy requests to /api/ endpoints. I'm seeking advice on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it.

It was a CORS and NGINX conf problem (I had to remove some stuff in my nginx conf):
Here was middleware.js before :
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
  credentials: true,
}));

and after
app.use(cors({
  origin: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? ['https://example.com'] : 'http://localhost:3000',
  methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
  credentials: true,
}));


There is no way that would have resulted in a 404

I'd say it's more likely that you changed the proxy_pass value to remove the trailing /

Yeah true, I’ve also removed unused stuff so my error wasn’t 404 anymore but just a Can’t GET / error

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
